# Performance testing using E2E Protractor

Tags: angular, protractor, angular-e2e

**Hi All!**
I have protractor E2E Protractor test case in our application. Currently am doing R&D for getting performance information like script execution, memory consumption using our protractor test case.

**My requirement :**
I need to execute my protractor test case for multiple times
I need list out all API calls for that specific test execution along with details like api response/request time.
For each test case , I need script execution time, memory consumption, page rendering time.
Once execution done, i need to display above information in the form of report.

**Benefits:**

Once above requirement is done , we can do UI performance testing using protractor. Same protractor test case we can execution number of time in single shot. Once after the execution we can see the reports to get performance relevant information.Instead of doing all things manually in developer tools, we can achieving in automation

**Thanks**

Comment: I'm not sure Protractor is the best tool for this job TBH. Not speaking of the fact it's deprecated.

Comment: Is there any other way to automate this feature??

Comment: there is, but you have 10 questions in one. Be specific and start one by one. For example how to extract requests duration while running protractor. But don't forget to mention what you tried and what didn't work

Comment: in short everything is possible

Comment: I would look at TestBench that the Angular repo uses. Behind the scenes it is using Protractor. How it works? /shrug.

Comment: @cnishina I tried with angular bench press.But it not generating any report.Even i dint find any number articles for that, no workable solution.